# Why are there exceptions for the i before e except after c rule?

Tags: rules

The exceptions such as"foreign" and "weird" seem abnormal to me because most of the rest of the ie or ei words follow the i before e rule.  They don't have a "c". Why does that happen?

Answer (score 1):

Because the usual formation of that *rule* is [incomplete](http://www.steve.wagar.com/ibeforee.htm) and there really isn't a [simple fix](http://www.ibeforee.org/). The *correct rule* should apparently be (from the first link),

> Use I before E
>
> Except when C is followed by L, P, T or V
>
> Or when sounded like "A" as in weight or "I" as in height
>
> Or when a prefix or suffix implies E-I.
>
> (Note that this means I before E after C the rest of the time!)

**Note** that there are still **exceptions** to the *correct* form of the rule,

> **The one I-E exception is:** society (C followed by T but not E-I) (well, 3 if you count societal and societies) Of course this exception fools no one because "ie" is not a digraph in this case so the order is obvious.
>
> **The E-I exceptions are:** albeit, neither, counterfeit, either, foreign, geisha, forfeit, heifer, herein, keister, leisure, peignoir, reveille, seize, sheik, sovereign, surfeit, therein, weir, weird, wherein [and variants like foreigner, forfeiture, seizure, sheikdom, weirdo, weirder]. The rare ones are: ceinture, enceinte, mullein, teiid, and villein. Of these, albeit, herein, therein and wherein are not digraphs so fool no one.

Answer (score 0):

Words come into English from many different sources, with various West Germanic dialects and Norman French being the most significant. The fact that *I* tends to comes before *E* in most of our most commonly used words is a bit of a coincidence. When an *E* and an *I* are together, one of them has to come first, and *-ie-* is helped by the fact that words ending in *-y* usually convert to *-ie-* when made plural or past tense.

The "except after *C*" exception is mainly due to Anglo-Norman's heavy use of *-ceivre-* as a word root, from Latin *capere*, "to take" (e.g., *receive*, *deceive*, *conceit*, and so forth).